Is it correct to say "the figure proliferated from A to B"?
I wrote:

The figures for both men and women at the age of 75 proliferated from 34 thousand and 47 thousand in 1911 to 181 thousand and 210 thousand, respectively, after the period.

Grammarly suggested that I change proliferated to increased. I wonder if it's because we don't often use proliferated with from...to.

No. Figures (numbers) can't proliferate. A figure can only increase or decrease.

Proliferate doesn't mean 'grow larger', it means 'become more numerous' (until there are lots of them).

No. Figures (numbers) can't proliferate. A figure can only increase or decrease.
Proliferate doesn't mean 'grow larger', it means 'become more numerous' (until there are lots of them).
